# Web based Data Transformation application

Tags: ssis, transformation

As per the business requirement I need to create a website which will provide functionality to the end user to transform the input data and get the output data in specified formatted, user can also save the format specification in a template for future modification and use, so that he don't need to provide all format specification every time while transforming data. I thought in my mind to achieve this, I will provide a webpage to get all transformation specification and after that I will create a SSIS package based on that specification and give a button on the website to user to run that SSIS whenever needed. there is one catch in this approach that there will be a delay when user submit his format specification and creation SSIS package and if user modifying the specification very often then SSIS modification is required every time and it will cost time and money every time.
Please provide any suggestion or guidance how can I achieve this

I would truly appropriate any suggestion on this.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible (not easy) to automatically write SSIS packages. The package itself is defined as an XML file and you can write code to write the XML and import that as a package into an SSIS catalog.

Taking that approach you could meet your requirements using SSIS with minimal delay after each specification change (just a few seconds to code-gen the package and load it to the catalog) and without additional cost per specification change.

To be honest though, I would question whether SSIS is the right tool for the job. Writing the SSIS XML is not trivial, and getting it wrong could leave your database server failing in unexpected ways.

Comment: Hi Brian, Thanks for you reply, if you think SSIS is not the right approach to meet this requirement then what would be the best approach to do this task. Thanks, Yogi.

Comment: That is very hard to say without knowing your requirement in more detail. If you need a lot of the power and flexibility of SSIS (all the different data sources and data flow transforms, etc) then perhaps it is the best option. There are also other ETL tools out there that are easier to code-gen. There is also the option (if your requirements are actually quite simple) of rolling your own. Have your site write the transforms in your format to be executed by your code. It all depends on your precise requirements.

Comment: A quick Google has suggested you might want to look at http://mixdem.sourceforge.net/ It looks on the surface to be similar to your requirement: a web-based UI that produces ETL transforms to be run by its own ETL engine. You could also look at a commercial product like Clover ETL. Their community projects might include a UI that you can use. http://www.cloveretl.com/

Comment: Hi Brian, Primarily source file would be in txt, xls, xlsx, .csv, MS-Access, SQL data format.

Comment: I cant help you any more. You are going to have to do your own research and decide how to proceed. Any ETL tool will probably be able to use either direct connections or ODBC to read from the sources you mentioned. There are ways of code-generating SSIS packages, just ask Google or Bing. Any more specific answer needs analysis that you are not likely to get here.